# Passing Countdown Timer beetwen Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm trying to pass the a CountDownTimer value from `Activity` 1(`PrimerNivel)` to `Activity` 2(`SegundoNivel`)and start the `CountDownTimer` in `Activity` 2 from the value that got from the `Activity` 1.

But the `CountDownTimer` in `Activity` 2 is reset to zero. I can't find the error. could someone help me?

**This is the code
Activity 1:**

```
public class PrimerNivel extends InicioActivity {
    private TextView cuentaRegresiva;
    long startTime = 60 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    long tiempoRestante;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.juego);
    cuentaRegresiva=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cuentaRegresiva);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    cuentaRegresiva.setText(cuentaRegresiva.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

}

 public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
              public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
                  super(startTime, interval);

              }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        cuentaRegresiva.setText("");


                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        tiempoRestante= millisUntilFinished;
                        cuentaRegresiva.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                        }}
OnClickListener siguiente =new OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {

                         Intent aNivelSiguiente = new Intent(PrimerNivel.this, SegundoNivel.class);
                         aNivelSiguiente.putExtra("regresivaAnterior", tiempoRestante);
                        startActivity(aNivelSiguiente);
                        PrimerNivel.this.finish();




                                                      }};

           }
```

**Activity 2:**

```
public class SegundoNivel extends InicioActivity {
    private TextView cuentaRegresiva;
    long startTime;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Bundle bundle;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.juego);
    cuentaRegresiva=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cuentaRegresiva);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);


    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    startTime= bundle.getLong("regresivaAnterior")/1000;
    cuentaRegresiva.setText(""+startTime);
    countDownTimer.start(); 

}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
              public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
              }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        cuentaRegresiva.setText("");        
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        cuentaRegresiva.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `CountDownTimer` before getting the value. Simply move the code that creates the timer to below where you get the value.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.juego);
    cuentaRegresiva=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cuentaRegresiva);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    startTime= bundle.getLong("regresivaAnterior")/1000;

    // move it here after you've gotten the value
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    cuentaRegresiva.setText(""+startTime);
    countDownTimer.start();
```

You may need to cancel your first timer to get the correct value at the correct time. Try calling

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
countDownTimer = null;
```

before creating the `Intent`. Also, you are dividing the `startTime` by 1000 after you get the value from the `Intent`. I'm not sure you want to be doing that.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? Disappears from where?

Comment: Sorry, in the second activity the textView appears with the value of the first activity for a second, but instantly disappears. This is the same error that i had.

Comment: Check what value you are getting in the `Intent` or change your `TextView` to display something like "Finished" in `onFinish()`. It is probably working as expected but the time you are using is too short so it calls `onFinish()` quickly and sets the text to an empty `String`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but how I can fix it?The interval is the same as the first activity. Sorry, I'm beginner

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want? Is it passing the value you expect when you click the button? If so, then I don't see the problem

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain very well. I want the countdown timer continues to run in the second Activity. The value passed activity ok but then ends immediately. If I remove countDownTimer. start (); (second activity) the value of the first activity appears. But otherwise the process ends.

Comment: Check my update and see if that helps. Not sure why you are dividing it by 1000

Comment: Your initial startTime value is 60000 ms. In activity2 you are dividing the remaining by 1000ms. If you push the button in Activity1 immediately you will at most get 6000 ms in Activity2. I think @codeMagic is right - Are you sure you want to divide by 1000?

Comment: You're right! This is the error. The code: startTime= bundle.getLong("regresivaAnterior");
Thank you codeMagic!!