# How do I prevent my CountDownTimer from running in background?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am making an Android app that has a time limit to the amount of points you can get. But if you close the app, the timer keeps going. How do I pause the `CountDownTimer` when the app pauses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cancel it in `onPause()` with something like

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    timer.cancel();    // timer is a reference to my inner CountDownTimer class
    timer = null;
}
```

And use the `millisUntilFinished` variable to save in a `SharedPreference` or some other persistent variable. Then use that variable again to start the timer in `onResume()`

[Shared Prefs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[This answer may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130057/passing-countdown-timer-beetwen-activities-in-android/27130218#27130218) if you need to pass the value to another `Activity`.