# Stop Android CountDownTimmer when another button is pressed

Tags: android, android-studio

So I designed an Android application about a year ago now in Android Studio to take care of some things at my college. However, I never "completely finished" it. The one thing that it is missing for me is when I click a button it starts a timer and outputs a string. However, if I press another button before that timer is up, it will say both at the same time. In looking online, I haven't found exactly what I was looking for so I thought I would open it up to the Stackoverflow community and maybe you can guide me in the right direction. Now for the code.

```
package com.example.james.texttospeech;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

    //TTS object
    private TextToSpeech myTTS;

    //status check code
    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    //create the Activity
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get a reference to the button element listed in the XML layout
        Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);


        //listen for clicks
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);


    }

    //respond to button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //get the text entered
        EditText enteredText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter);
        String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);

    }
    public void BRC (View view) {
        new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String words1 = ("BRC will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 + " minutes");
                speakWords(words1);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String words2 = ("BRC will form up right away");
                speakWords(words2);
            }
        }.start();


}


    public void SRC (View view1) {

        new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String words3 = ("SRC will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 +" minutes");
                speakWords(words3);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String words4=("SRC will form up right away");
                speakWords(words4);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void Taps (View view2) {

        new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String words5 = ("Taps will sound in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 +" minutes");
                speakWords(words5);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String words6=("Attention inside and outside of barracks the status in barracks is now Taps C C Q at the beginning of this turnout there was a status check");
                speakWords(words6);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void Penalty_Tours (View view3) {

        new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String words7 = ("P Tees will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 +" minutes");
                speakWords(words7);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String words8=("P Tees will form up right away");
                speakWords(words8);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void Colors (View view4) {

        String words9 = ("Colors Colors Colors");
        speakWords(words9);
    }

    public void PTT (View view5) {

        new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String words10 = ("P T T will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 +" minutes");
                speakWords(words10);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String words11=("P T T will form up right away");
                speakWords(words11);
            }
        }.start();

    }



    //speak the user text
    private void speakWords(String speech) {

        //speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }

    //act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

            }
            else {
                //no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    //setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void BRC(View view) {
    int totaltime = 6500;
    CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(totaltime, 6000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String words1 = ("BRC will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 + " minutes");
            speakWords(words1);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            String words2 = ("BRC will form up right away");
            speakWords(words2);
        }
    }.start();

void SRC() {
    mTimer.cancel();
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333742/how-do-i-prevent-my-countdowntimer-from-running-in-background/27333819#27333819

Comment: Once my Android Studio finishes updating I will take a look.

Comment: @codeMagic when I add a mTimer = new CountDownTimer it says cannot resolve symbol mTimer.

Comment: Sorry but that's not helpful without the actual code. You probably aren't declaring it... `CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer ()`

Comment: @codeMagic I added it to my original post. Furthermore, it has a red line after .start(); and the last }. Also the mTimer.cancel(); says cannot resolve symbol mTimer

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity function ,declare a variable to define the status of each counter. In onTick() of all counters, make it check for the variable

Hope this help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

//TTS object
private Boolean isBRCRunning = false;
private Boolean isPTTRunning = false;
private static CountDownTimer myBRC;
private static CountDownTimer myPTT;

//

    //respond to button clicks
public void onClick(View v) {

    // .....

    // If BRC button
    if(BRC button){
        BRC();
        isBRCRunning = true;
    } else if (PTT button){
        BRC();
        isBRCRunning = true;
    }

}

public void BRC () {
    myBRC = new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String words1 = ("BRC will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 + " minutes");
            MainActivity.logForDebug(MainActivity.TAG, words1);

            // Control other timer
            if(isPTTRunning){
                myPTT.cancel();
                isPTTRunning = false;
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            String words2 = ("BRC will form up right away");
            MainActivity.logForDebug(MainActivity.TAG, words2);
        }
    }.start();
}

public void PTT () {
    myPTT = new CountDownTimer(65000, 6000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String words1 = ("BRC will form up in" + millisUntilFinished / 6000 + " minutes");
            MainActivity.logForDebug(MainActivity.TAG, words1);

            // Control other timers
            if(isBRCRunning){
                myBRC.cancel();
                isBRCRunning = false;
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            String words2 = ("BRC will form up right away");
            MainActivity.logForDebug(MainActivity.TAG, words2);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Comment: When I place that first if statement in the onClick it says it cannot resolve the symbol for BRC and PTT. Also it says BRC (view) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (). That onClick outputs what is but into a textbox, it doesn't control all the clicks.

Comment: Code in onClick button is pseudo code. For "BRC/PTT button" in if , you have to modify to match your code, to identify if onClick() was called from BRC button or PTT button.